# JMS - Couldn't create session factory even if connection to remote provider is OK

Tags: java, jboss, jms, spring-jms, jms-topic

I make a jar to connect to JMS provider, it's work fine in a server (a) but doesn't work on a server (b).

I verify that connection to the JMS provider from server (b) is OK via telnet as shown below:

```
    -> telnet -d 10.127.161.247 4447
Trying 10.127.161.247...
Connected to 10.127.161.247.
```

The logs and exception that it's throw is below :

```
2018/08/01 11:19:47:921 - Processing command line arguments...
2018/08/01 11:19:47:927 - Preparing the output...  Writing to file = true
2018/08/01 11:19:50:315 - Trying to establish connection, attempt: 0
2018/08/01 11:19:52:132 - Connecting to provider: remote://10.127.161.247:4447 using user: oad_user
2018/08/01 11:19:52:132 - Creating a regular (non-secure) connection factory...
2018/08/01 11:19:53:073 - Opening a connection to the JMS provider...
2018/08/01 11:20:24:192 - Attempt failed: Failed to create session factory
javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:675)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTopicConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:267)
        at com.alcatel.ossgw.client.jms.JmsSubscriberClient.prepareConnection(JmsSubscriberClient.java:334)
        at com.alcatel.ossgw.client.jms.JmsSubscriberClient.connect(JmsSubscriberClient.java:274)
        at com.alcatel.ossgw.client.jms.JmsSubscriberClient.listen(JmsSubscriberClient.java:97)
        at com.alcatel.ossgw.client.jms.JmsSubscriberClient.main(JmsSubscriberClient.java:536)
Caused by: ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:818)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:67
```

I don't how to debug such a problem knowing i'm new in JMS, i'll be grateful for any remarks and ideas..

Many thanks

Comment: The test you did with telnet is from server b?

Comment: @losusovic yes the telnet is from server b.

Comment: remote://10.127.161.247:4447 sounds strange. it should be something like tcp://10.127.161.247:4447 - I think. Also even though you can do telnet, your API might expect a different protocol than ActiveMQ broker on port 4447 is providing.

Comment: @AxelPodehl Thanks for your answer, but it works fine if i run the jar from server (a)...

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever find out why this was happening?
I have a related issue where an active JMS connection suddenly disconnects and the system starts throwing this exception until a system restart is done and then it connects again without fail.

Comment: Same issue. The only thing I could do is to restart my IDE again and hope it does not fail after the restart.